# NestJS How to return array column to views in a database

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to retrieve in database lists of platforms with each platform retrieve the projects of this platform.

**See the picture**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atCu5.png)

I use View Entities to calculate the progress of each platform.
my problem is we have each platform project it leaves with an object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CawKy.png)

How can return an object from a platform that contains all projects?

Comment: Heya, I see you are new here. Some tips to help us help you; English might not be your first language, but try to proof read your question for error's. The link you posted still has some templated words in it. Also try to list what you have tried and what you aim to do technically, Lastly, add the code that is not working for you, maybe add some pseudo code in comments to show us what you meant.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Funonly I'm sorry I'm new, I added an explanation, hope this is enough.

Comment: @Community I'm sorry I'm new, I added an explanation, hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to the NestJs and I am stuck on a problem with returning response entities from my backend.
I used **view entity** because I have in complicated SQL computation as a platform advancement calculate.

The problem when using view it returns repetition of objects when that contains multiple projects and members.

[image]

How do I return a platform object that contains an array of projects and members objects?

i want it like that :

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dev factory",
    "projects": [
      {
         "createdAt": "2022-01-11T10:29:42.000Z",
         "updatedAt": "2022-01-11T10:29:42.000Z",
         "deletedAt": null,
         "id": 2,
         "name": "API",
         "description": "efqzf",
        },{
         "createdAt": "2022-01-11T10:29:42.000Z",
         "updatedAt": "2022-01-11T10:29:42.000Z",
         "deletedAt": null,
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Web",
         "description": "efqsszf",
         }],
   "advancement": 50,
   "dueDate": null,
   "status": "In prograss"
}
```

The code below.

platform.entity.ts

```
import { Project } from '@routes/projects/entities/project.entity';
import { User } from '@routes/users/entities/user.entity';
import { ViewColumn, ViewEntity } from 'typeorm';

@ViewEntity({
  expression: `
SELECT 
      "platforms"."id" AS "id", 
      "platforms"."name" AS "name",
      "platforms"."releaseDate" AS "dueDate",
      "users"."id" AS "memberId",
      "users"."firstName" AS "memberFirstName",
      "users"."lastName" AS "memberLastName",
      ((cast(("done_tickets"."tickets_statusId") as float) / count ("tickets"."id")) * 100 ) AS "advancement" , 
      ("done_tickets"."tickets_statusId") AS "tickets_done", 
      count ("tickets"."id") AS  "tickets_count",
      CASE
        WHEN ((cast(("done_tickets"."tickets_statusId") as float) / count ("tickets"."id")) * 100 )>0 
            AND ((cast(("done_tickets"."tickets_statusId") as float) / count ("tickets"."id")) * 100 )<100 THEN 'In Progress'
        WHEN ((cast(("done_tickets"."tickets_statusId") as float) / count ("tickets"."id")) * 100 ) = 100 THEN  'Done'
        ELSE 'To Do'
      END AS status
FROM 
      "platforms" "platforms" 
LEFT JOIN 
        "users" AS "users" ON "platforms"."adminUserId" = "users"."id"
LEFT JOIN 
      "projects" "projects" ON "projects"."platformId"="platforms"."id" 
LEFT JOIN 
      "tickets" "tickets" ON "tickets"."projectId"="projects"."id" 
LEFT JOIN ( 
      SELECT "platforms"."id" AS "platformId" , 
          count ("tickets"."statusId") as "tickets_statusId" 
      FROM "platforms" "platforms" 
      LEFT JOIN "projects" "projects" ON "projects"."platformId"="platforms"."id" 
      LEFT JOIN "tickets" "tickets" ON "tickets"."projectId"="projects"."id" 
      LEFT JOIN "ticket_statuses" "status" ON  "status"."id"="tickets"."statusId" 
      WHERE "tickets"."statusId" = 5 
      GROUP BY "platforms"."id" ) "done_tickets" ON  "platforms"."id"="done_tickets"."platformId" 
LEFT JOIN "ticket_statuses" "status" ON "status"."id"="tickets"."statusId"  
GROUP BY "platforms"."id" , "done_tickets"."tickets_statusId" , "users"."id"
`,
})
export class ProgressPlatform {
  @ViewColumn()
  id!: number;

  @ViewColumn()
  name!: string;

  @ViewColumn()
  advancement!: Float64Array;

  @ViewColumn()
  dueDate!: Date;

  @ViewColumn()
  projects!: Project[]; <-- here is the problem

  @ViewColumn()
  members!: User[]; <-- here is the problem

  @ViewColumn()
  status!: string;
}
```

platform.service.ts

```
async findAll(
    options: PaginationParamsInterface,
  ): Promise<PaginatedInterface<ProgressPlatform>> {
    const [platforms, totalCount] = await Promise.all([
      this.platformsProgressRepository.find({
        skip: paginationUtils.getSkipCount(options.page, options.limit),
        take: paginationUtils.getLimitCount(options.limit),
      }),
      this.platformsProgressRepository.count(),
    ]);

    return { paginatedResult: platforms, totalCount };
  }
```

platform.controller.ts

```
  @ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ type: () => MessageResponseDto })
  @Version('1')
  @Get('all-platforms')
  @Serialize(AllPlatformsResponseDto)
  @ApiExtraModels(AllPlatformsResponseDto)
  @ApiQuery({ name: 'page', required: false })
  @ApiQuery({ name: 'limit', required: false })
  async findAll(@Query('page') page?: number, @Query('limit') limit?: number) {
    const paginatedTickets: PaginatedInterface<ProgressPlatform> =
      await this.platformsService.findAll({ page, limit });
    return responseUtils.success(
      'platforms',
      paginatedTickets.paginatedResult,
      {
        totalCount: paginatedTickets.totalCount,
      },
    );
  }
```